# Why password is not hashed when create user?

Tags: python, django

I've created a custom user model and in the register page if I set a password on submit, the browser does not let me to save because the password is empty even if when it is filled. In the admin panel If I want to create a user on submit, the password box remains in plain text. How can I fix that?

```
# My user model

class Crescatori(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
""" Model Crescatori, folosit la inregistrarea utilizatorilor"""

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True, db_index=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    nume = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    prenume = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    telefon = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    strada = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    numarul = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    judet = models.CharField(_('Judet/Sector'), max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    tara = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['nume', 'prenume', 'judet', 'tara']
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Crescator"
        verbose_name_plural = "Crescatori"

    def get_short_name(self):
        """ Returneaza numele mic al crescatorului"""

        return self.nume

    def get_full_name(self):
        """ Returneaza numele complet al crescatorului"""

        return '%s %s' % (self.nume, self.prenume)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

# User Manager

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """ Manager crescatori/useri inregistrati"""

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """ Functie pentru crearea utilizatorilor"""

        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('Adresa de email nu poate fi necompletata'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """ Functie pentru crearea adminilor"""

        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Pentru administratori nu a fost setat is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

# My view

class RegisterView(CreateView):
    """ Modul pentru crearea formularului de inregistrare"""
    model = Crescatori
    fields = ['nume', 'prenume', 'judet', 'tara', 'password', 'email']
    template_name = 'myapp/registration.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """Functie pentru criptarea parolei """

        # Hash password before sending it to super
        form.instance.password = make_password(form.instance.password)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Is there something that I missed? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
# your can use set_password function

user = user_form.save()
user.set_password(user.password) # create the hashed password
user.save() # then save it
```

Comment: I don' t have a form class. I use create view so I haven't define a form. That function where must be put?